# Troubleshooting RStata with StataBE 17; Error in seq.int(cutpoints[1] + 1, cutpoints[2] - 1) : 'from' must be a finite number

Tags: r, stata

Using the package RStata in R-Studio with StataBE 17 on Mac OS yields a issue with cutpoints, that has not been resolved.

Reference: Another "Error in seq.int(cutpoints[1] + 1, cutpoints[2] - 1) : 'from' must be a finite number" problem · Issue #28 · lbraglia/RStata · GitHub

```
# Load Packages 
install.packages("RStata")
library(RStata)

# Set Path & Version
options("RStata.StataPath" = "/Applications/Stata/StataBE.app/Contents/MacOS/StataBE")
options("RStata.StataVersion" = 17.0)

# Test Generic Code
stata("di 2+2")
--------------------
> stata("di 2+2")
Error in seq.int(cutpoints[1] + 1, cutpoints[2] - 1) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
```

I have tried searching online but the solutions for updating the path only seem to work on older versions of Stata. I have updated my packages and software, and tried to hard code the cutpoints.

Comment: Check if path `"/Applications/Stata/StataBE.app/Contents/MacOS/StataBE"` is correctly specified. The error message might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with this package, but a quick look suggests that you may need to point to the non-GUI, console p version of Stata:

```
> library(RStata)
> 
> # Set Path & Version
> options("RStata.StataPath" = "/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app/Contents/MacOS/stata-mp")
> options("RStata.StataVersion" = 17.0)
> 
> # Test Generic Code
> stata('di 2+2')
. di 2+2
4
```

I don't have BE, but here's how I found the MP path on my machine from the terminal:

```
$ which stata-mp
/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app/Contents/MacOS/stata-mp
```

Hopefully you just need to type state-be instead.